# How to identify the data type of the function argument

Tags: casting, type-conversion

In many cases we keep the function input as (void *) and typecast it to required data type inside the function.
But is there any way to identify the real data type of the passed variable inside this function?

void func (void * x);

Here it can take arguments of many types. How to identify the what type has been passed to it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your code is in C (please clarify that, preferably with a tag).

No, there is no way to do this. `void*` is a raw memory pointer with no information on what it points to. You could cast it to ANY type, but it might not be valid (most likely it will contain garbage when trying to be interpreted in the wrong way, that can and will cause further problems).

One should always try to avoid `void*` unless necessary to use, exactly because that - it can circumvent all type checking in your code, any everything that builds on it.

Without knowing what is your goal with `void*` all I can say is no, there is no way to recover type information. There might be a solution for your problem without `void*`. If not, and thus you must use `void*`, there is still a trick to pass some type information with it: bundle the `void*` pointer in a struct along with an `enum` that will hold the type information. This can work, but will require some boilerplate code and you must be careful implementing it to avoid problems.